# Setting\Getting Environment Variables through batch file inside java program

Tags: java

I am facing a problem where I need to run a bat file from java program.
This Batch file contains certain SET ms-dos command which i need to access further down in my application.

I used ProcessBuilder Class to invoke the batch file but processBuilder.environment() is not returning me the variables set by the batch file.

DOS SET command sets the variables on that prompt only.

I am unable to find the solution for this problem.

Is there any ulternate approach for such issue. I cant change the Batch file.

Regards
Abhay

Comment: Could you post the batch code? There might be an issue there?

Answer (score 0):

[System.getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) lets you get an environmental variable. It should work in this context too. There is [another version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29) which returns a `Map` of environmental variables.

Comment: I Tried System.getenv but its returning me only those property set in explicity in mycom->properties->environment variables.

Comment: Its not returning me the properties that I had set in the batch file. Through Ms-Dos SET command

Comment: This is my Function
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String path = "D:\\build\\XL_7_12\\XL_7_12\\build\\xl_env.cmd";
  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(path);
  Process process = null;
  try {
   process = processBuilder.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
  for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
   System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
  }

 }

Comment: This is Batch file entry
set ROOT=D:
set FOLDER=build\712

Answer (score 0):

Your ProcessBuilder instance holds the environment variables used by the child process.  You should reference `processBuilder.environment()` rather than referencing the environment variables for the parent process found in `System.getenv()`.

However, you may find that it's still a one-way street.  You can set environment variables there to pass to your process shell, but the changes made by the SET commands will not survive the return trip.

So, here's an alternate approach.  Write a batch file as a wrapper script and have that output your desired variables to somewhere more easily accessed, like stdout, stderr, or a file.

```
wrapper.bat
===========
@echo off
call "D:\build\XL_7_12\XL_7_12\build\xl_env.cmd"
echo ROOT=%ROOT%,FOLDER=%FOLDER%
```

Then you call your `wrapper.bat` from Java and collect and parse the ROOT and FOLDER values from the last line of your process.getInputStream().

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I guess I have to follow the approch suggested above. Getting details from process.getInputStram

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to redirect the output of the ECHO command to a file, then read this later from Java. eg.

```
echo ROOT=%ROOT%,FOLDER=%FOLDER% > \temp\vars.txt
```

Then read \temp\vars.txt from java. This might be a little easier than reading the input stream. Finally, be aware that instead of a wrapper.bat file, you can issue two commands to a single copy of the command.exe interperter,, thus sharing environments, so you could:

```
D:\build\XL_7_12\XL_7_12\build\xl_env.cmd & ECHO %ROOT% > \temp\vars.txt
```